# How to use both Time::Local and Time::localtime together in perl

Tags: perl, scripting

I don't have any advanced date or time utilities in my Perl installation. I have only `Time::Local`, `Time::gmtime`, `Time::localtime` and `Time::tm`.

```perl
use Time::Local;
#use Time::localtime;

#$datestring = localtime('2018/07/17-21:18:15','%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S');

my $str = '2018/07/17-21:18:15';

my ($date, $time) = split /-/, $str;
my ($year, $mon, $day) = split /\//, $date;
my ($hour, $min, $sec) = split /:/, $time;
--$mon;

my $time  = timelocal($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year);
my $time2 = localtime;
my $time3 = localtime;

print "time is $time, $time2, $time3\n";
```

After executing the above I get

```
time is 1531880295, Mon Jul 23
10:50:54 2018, Mon Jul 23 10:50:54 2018
```

After uncommenting the second line I get the following (with `tm
 structure)

```
time is 1531880295, Time::tm=ARRAY(0x40036a40),
Time::tm=ARRAY(0x40036ab8)
```

I want to use both of the functionalities and use them like this

```
time is 1531880295, Mon Jul 23 10:50:54 2018,
Time::tm=ARRAY(0x40036ab8)
```

Comment: Which version of Perl are you running? Run `perl -v` and tell us please. Usually there is more than one directory where Perl keeps modules. The best way to check if you have something installed (and what version) is to run `perl -MTime::Piece\ 999` (with a backslash ``\`` and an empty space). It'll tell you either what version you have or say you don't have it.

Comment: Also, please tell us what you are actually trying to do. Why do you want to use those together? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using 5.8.2 version.

Comment: The reason why I am using together is that I don't have any new time modules (or) date modules with me, I want to use Time::Piece but could not as I don't have it. I am trying to convert the string into time ( I don't have POSIX::qw as well). So finally with no other options left I have to use timelocal funciton for that I need (Time::Local), I need tm structure as well to print formatted output into a file(Time::Local). and I need localtime in order to get the time of a function that it takes. I am placing start and end and then computing the time.

Comment: There's no POSIX::qw. If you do `use POSIX qw(foo bar)` that means it imports the functions `foo` and `bar` from the POSIX module. In Perl 5.8.2 POSIX was included. See [here](https://perldoc.pl/5.8.2/POSIX)

Comment: sorry, I mean to say there is no POSIX module also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're trying to work out how a Perl module works, it's always a good idea to read the documentation. The documentation for the two modules you're using is at [Time::Local](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local) and [Time::localtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::localtime). The documentation for Time::localtime includes this line:

> The ctime() function provides a way of getting at the scalar sense of the original CORE::localtime() function.

So you can get the behaviour you want by changing your code to:

```
my $time = timelocal($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year);
my $time2 = ctime;
my $time3 = localtime;
print "time is $time, $time2, $time3\n";
```

But, as simbabque says in his comment, this seems a rather strange thing to want to do and if you explained what you're trying to achieve we could almost certainly show you a better way to do it.

Comment: As mentioned in previous post comment, the reason why I am using together is that I don't have any new time modules (or) date modules with me, I want to use Time::Piece but could not as I don't have it. I am trying to convert the string into time ( I don't have POSIX::qw as well). So finally with no other options left I have to use timelocal funciton for that I need (Time::Local), I need tm structure as well to print formatted output into a file(Time::Local). and I need localtime in order to get the time of a function that it takes. I am placing start and end and then computing the time.

Comment: If you don't have POSIX, then you have a fundamentally broken Perl installation and you should refuse to use it until it is fixed!

Comment: i will let the relevant people know, I don’t have rights to upgrade also, thanks